# Using Contains in LINQ for "IN" clause - different between strings and bytes

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I'm trying to create a LINQ query to pull specific subTypes, which are stored as Bytes in the table. I've tried several variations, and got it working forcing in and out of strings; but I can't get a numeric version to work. I assume it's some sort of c# rule I don't properly understand, but I'm not sure where to look. Any suggestions?

```
// This works okay, but doesn't makes sense to go in/out of string

string[] subTypes = { "2", "4" };      //  2 = Clinic, 4 = SubClinic
var clinics = from o in db.Locations
         where subTypes.Contains(o.LocationType.ToString())
        select o.Name;

// this version shows an error on the "where" clause
// byte[] does not contain a definition for 'Contains'...

byte[] subType = { 2, 4 };      //  2 = Clinic, 4 = SubClinic
var clinic = from o in db.Locations
        where subType.Contains(o.LocationType) 
       select  o.Name;
```

Comment: define "can't get [it] to work"

Comment: What is the type of the property o.LocationType?

Comment: I am a little rusty on my EF, does `where subType.Any(x=> x == o.LocationType)` work?

Comment: Entity Framework does funny things with byte[]: https://lehmamic.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/troubles-with-byte-arrays-an-entity-framework/

Comment: o.LocationType is defined as tinyint, which I assumed was the same as byte; they're not so I needed to say subType.Contains(byte)o.LocationType)

Comment: I would have tried a lambda, but the actual "where" clause is much more complex than the snippet with the problem, so I hesitated to go that route.

Comment: I see the downvote and I apologize if my question wasn't up to your rigorous standards. I _did_ do research, but all the answers I found related to strings, I couldn't find anything where the problem centered around numeric types. As for question presentment, I tried to condense the question down to the minimum necessary to frame the part where I was confused. I thought I was doing something wrong in the way I was building the list/array; it didn't occur to me that it was a type casting issue. I thank you very much for the answers and for your tolerance of my poor question-framing skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when I tried:

```
byte[] subType = { 2, 4 };
var locationType = 2;
Console.WriteLine(subType.Contains(locationType));
Console.ReadLine();
```

I got the same error as you did.  Changing the code to:

```
byte[] subType = { 2, 4 };
var locationType = (byte)2;
Console.WriteLine(subType.Contains(locationType));
Console.ReadLine();
```

It worked fine.  Is it possible that the LocationType is not a byte but an int?

Comment: By "can't get it to work" I meant that the compiler was showing an error about Contains. 

I'm guessing that a SQL type of tinyint and a c# type of byte are not 100% compatible, so the cast was needed.
       
`byte[] subType = { 2, 4 };      //  2 = Clinic, 4 = SubClinic`
`    var clinic = from o in db.Locations`
`                   where subType.Contains((byte)o.LocationType)`
`                   select o.Name;`

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using the `var` keyword, your locationType variable is defined like an int.

```
var locationType = 2;
// Equivalent to
int locationType = 2;
```

When there are any ambiguity, use explicit type declaration :

```
byte locationType = 2;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm not declaring locationType as a var. locationType is an attribute in a SQL DB table and is defined as tinyint. I thought tinyint and byte were the same, so it didn't occur to me that I needed a cast for force tinyint to byte. Your answer is right, and helpful, except the explicit typing needs to occur in the c# code, can't do anything about how the DB is built.

Comment: May be you can change the type of the column in SQL Server or cast the result in SQL if you truly stored a byte